# Term for expected randomized given advice string?

Tags: complexity-theory, randomness

Problems which run in deterministic polynomial time given polynomial sized advice are in class P/poly.

Problems which run in probabilistic polynomial time given polynomial sized advice are still in class P/poly.

What about problems which have an expected randomized polynomial time given polynomial sized advice under uniform distribution of inputs where expected here signifies average in the sense that a very small portion of inputs are allowed to run in exponential time using the algorithm?

Comment: Please distinguish average polynomial time and expected polynomial time.

Comment: I have already clarified in last sentence.

Comment: Also, please be clear which distributions are used over the inputs. Uniform distribution leads to exactly $\mathsf{E/poly}$

Comment: Are you talking about languages decidable using probabilistic (expected) polynomial time Turing machines with polynomial advice?

Comment: @WillardZhan clarified better.

Comment: @Ariel I am not talking of zpp or zpe.